# Backbone Collection and Model url, bulk model collection save

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

I want to achieve.

**1.** Creating a single model on model.save should point to `url` mentioned in Models attributes

**2.** I want to do a bulk save ( ***how can i do that*** ). So, as per example, say I have arrays of books model and I want to   save it at once using Collection's url.

```
var BookModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   idAttribute: 'id',
   url: function() {
     return 'http:/test.com/books/addsinglebook'
   },
   defaults: {
     id: null,
     name: ''
  },
});

var BookCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: 'http:/test.com/books/addbulkbooks',
  model: BookModel,   
});

// bookmodel.save() should point to /addsinglebook
// bookcollection.somesavemethod() should point to /addbulkbooks
```

Since Backbone collection doesn't have a `save` and `create` is for a single model, do I need to add my own method to the prototype for implementing a bulk save?

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Use [`urlRoot`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot)

```
var BookModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   idAttribute: 'id',
   urlRoot: 'http:/test.com/books/addsinglebook',
   defaults: {
     id: null,
     name: ''
  },
});
```

**2.** Your should implement your own `save` and `create`, cause backbone supports basic RESTfull API, which on in it's order doesn't support bulk update/create. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12287359/save-several-backbone-models-at-once) and [here](https://github.com/akiomik/backbone-batch-operations) for similar solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to add your own method to the Collection's class for implementing a bulk save. There you can use Underscore's `each` method to iterate through models of the Collection:

```
var BookCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
...
    bulkSave: function() {
        this.each(model.save);
    }
...
```